# What should I look for when buying a frameless mirror?

Tags: mirror

What should I look for when buying a frameless, full length mirror to mount on a bedroom wall?  It will be mounted close to a light switch (not that I think that matters).  I understand that mirrors come in all kinds of thickness.  Would 5mm suffice for this purpose and is there anything else I should consider before purchasing?

Comment: How are you going to hang it and mount it? Availability of hardware would be important.

Comment: Mounted in this fashion: http://video.about.com/apartments/Mount-a-Frameless-Wall-Mirror.htm

Comment: Not all walls can handle thick nails, see if your wall can?

Comment: Your face, otherwise the mirror is not doing it's job!

Comment: I always glued large bathroom mirrors (either by myself with clear silicone, or the contractors did it). I never used hardware. For large sheets, gluing is much safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a straight edge to make sure there are no high spots on the wall.As the glass will not flex if the wall has an outward bulge the glass may break when you tighten the mounting brackets.Make sure that nothing will contact the mirror during regular activities,opening doors ,cabinets,drawfronts etc.It is also not advisable to mount it next to a doorway such as a bedroom door as it might be confused with the exit in an emergency.Think middle of the night and the smokealarm going off.